# React-Redux Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, react-redux

I am facing this error whenever I try to delete or add a schedule using react-redux functionality. Even though I get the error, if I go back to the dashboard then return to the schedule page, the schedule will be added/deleted.

[Error Message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rGwb.jpg)

**actions/schedule.js**

```
export const addSchedule = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/schedule', formData, config);
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_SCHEDULE,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Schedule created', 'success'));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: SCHEDULE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};

export const deleteSchedule = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.delete(`/api/schedule/${id}`);
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_SCHEDULE,
      payload: id,
    });
    dispatch(setAlert('Schedule removed', 'danger'));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: SCHEDULE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};
```

**reducers/schedule.js**

```
const initialState = {
  schedule: [],
  loading: true,
  error: {},
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case GET_SCHEDULE:
      return {
        ...state,
        schedule: payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case ADD_SCHEDULE:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: [payload, ...state.posts],
        loading: false,
      };
    case SCHEDULE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case DELETE_SCHEDULE:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.filter((post) => post._id !== payload),
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**routes/api/schedule**

```
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    auth,
    [
      check('from', 'From field is required').not().isEmpty(),
      check('to', 'To field is required').not().isEmpty(),
      check('zoomcall', 'zoomcall field is required').not().isEmpty(),
      check('name', 'name field is required').not().isEmpty(),
    ],
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
      const newSchedule = new Schedule({
        date: req.body.date,
        from: req.body.from,
        to: req.body.to,
        zoomcall: req.body.zoomcall,
        name: user.name,
        user: req.user.id,
      });
      const schedule = await newSchedule.save();
      res.json(schedule);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);

router.delete('/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // req.params.id is grabbed from the URL
    const schedule = await Schedule.findById(req.params.id);

    // Post doesn't exist
    if (!schedule) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Schedule not found' });
    }
    //Check User
    if (schedule.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'User not authorized' });
    }
    await schedule.remove();

    res.json({ msg: 'Schedule deleted' });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.kind == 'ObjectId') {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Schedule not Found' });
    }
    console.error(err.message);
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

If anyone needs more details, I have my Github as well. When running it, make sure to use 'npm start' in the server folder to get it going. (Error on my part.)
https://github.com/corycoupe/Clear-Skies-Redux

Comment: Well the error looks pretty self-explanatory. `err.response` is undefined, so trying to access subproperties of it will throw that error. You should print `err` to see what it actually is

Comment: Following the guidelines of StackOverflow, `code` or `logs` should be provided in `text format, not images.` Can you refer to the guide below and correct it?
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  /  [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: As @Jayce444 mentioned, based on the error you get, the ```err``` object does not have the ```response``` property. What is the shape of ```err``` when you log it? 
Also, when you do a request to the back-end, you need to specify the full url of the back-end.